# How to carve half of a Thanksgiving Turkey?

Tags: php, image-processing

I have a cool problem. I'm trying to highlight exactly 50% of this turkey's mass. In practice it will not be 50%, but if I can get 50%, I can figure the rest out.

My current idea is this: Scan in every pixel to find out the mass of the turkey, in pixels. Then, when I want 50% of the turkey, highlight pixels from left to right until I've highlighted 50% of the pixels.

Does anyone have any better ideas? This is the slowest, brute-force idea that requires looping over every pixel once to count the pixels and again to highlight 50% of them.

Note that dividing the picture vertically would not leave 50% of the turkey, as the turkey's body is a lot meatier than it's neck.

[image: This is a Turkey]

Comment: Whoever voted to close this.. This is a serious problem. I'm trying to make an infographic that colors a turkey based on some percentages.

Comment: @DanRedux: But at its current state, it's not a programming problem. You're only asking about methods; *how* you would go about doing this. It's more on-topic for Programmers.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to highlight 50% of the pixels rather than 50% of some linear measure? I don't think people are good at judging volume or area by looking at complex shapes.

Answer (score 3):

You say the percentage will change, but I'm going to go on a limb here and assume the turkey itself won't.

So you don't need to loop twice. You only need to do it once, map the data into some form of structure that you can reference, then only refer to it each time you need to highlight to figure out how far you need to go.

For instance, make an associative array of `<percentage of mass (integer out of a hundred) => vertical column number (int)>`

That way, when you need to shade x percent, you only need to loop over cached_data[percent_to_highlight] columns of pixels, shading them all, and then break out of the loop entirely once you reach it.

---

For even more performance, have two pictures - one fully shaded plus your normal one. The associative array should map `percentage => byte_offset`

For each image you wish to generate, simply memcpy or whatever PHP's equivalent of a fast, ranged copy from `0 -> byte_offset` of the shaded picture over the non-shaded and save. No more looping. You can't get faster than this.

Comment: Actually, this is what I'm already doing.. I should have specified, but yes, if I was doing my method, I would convert it into a stream of pixels and them stream a certain percentage of them.

Comment: If you're doing exactly what I posted... how can you get any better performance than O(N/x) where x is the inverse of the amount you need shaded?

Comment: Possibly by using some sort of tree/matrix of pixels that I can highlight... Like, if I ask for 10%, surely I could take some shortcuts as opposed to cycling through 10% of the pixels and drawing them.. I'm thinking of any other format that would make it less than O(n/x)..

Answer (score 0):

The problem does not look to have a smart algorithm over the top of my head to do it. But then I am not an expert in CG too so I might be wrong on that.

And trying to look for such solution can very well increase the time complexity (than O(n))if you end up using nested loops on n, where n being total number of pixels used by the turkey.

Instead doing the two pass way is very easy to implement(very less time/effort to implement) and also will be O(n) neglecting the constant 2 which is not a bad solution. 
Depending on for what purpose, hardware, space constraint, etc you are writing this solution for; going the two pass way might be more rewarding.